# How can I synchronize project dependencies between developers?

Tags: python, git, github, version-control, pip

My team is starting a new Python project. We will be using Git with a central repository. Each developer will work on a local virtualenv, and push/pull from the central repo to the local one.

Using this setting, here is a possible scenario:

1. Developer A installs a package and writes some code that uses it.
2. He/she pushes the code to the central repo.
3. Developer B pulls the code and starts working.
4. Developer B runs the project locally and gets an ImportError, because he/she hadn't installed the new dependency introduced by Developer A.

My question is: how can I synchronize the project dependencies between all developers?

An approach I considered:

**Before** any **`git push`**, the developer performs `git freeze > requirements.txt`. The file is pushed along with the code.

**After** any **`git pull`**, the developer performs `git install -r requirements.txt`.

Is this approach vaiable? Is it recommended? Are there better approaches?

Answer (score 5):

I would use virtualenv and create a requirements file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

that you add to your git repo, every time a new package is needed, it should be added to the requirements file.  When a developer pulls they can run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I think this is the most logical approach and is one my team has used multiple times.

Comment: This is what my team does, too. It works well at keeping everybody on the same track.

Comment: Thanks for answering. A question: how is this different than the `install_requires` in `setup.py`? Which file should I have in my app, a `requirements.txt` or a `setup.py`?

Comment: install_requires in setup.py is typically for installing a package and its dependencies.  You could in principle create this for your project, which might be useful when the project is finished and you want to deploy it.  In the interim, this is setting up the packages in your python environment so all developers can work at the same time using the same libraries.  The beauty of virtualenv is that I can setup one for every project that I'm working on and I don't have to worry about dependency issue while working on multiple projects.

Comment: This is also what we do in all our projects (and our company works on many Python projects).