# What should I use to manage package dependencies in my team: requirements.txt or setup.py?

Tags: python, version-control, pip

Recently I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344874/how-can-i-synchronize-project-dependencies-between-developers) about how a team can synchronize package dependencies between all developers when working on an application.

The single answer was to keep a `requirements.txt` file in the central repository. After installing a package on the local virtualenv, a developer can `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and push that with the code. After pulling the other developers can `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

This would work, but I want to compare this to a different approach and understand how they are different and which is better.

The different approach is having a `setup.py` in the repository, and specifying the dependencies in `install_requires`.

Which approach is more suitable for a team working on an application? I know `setup.py` is usually used in reusable libraries as opposed to self-contained apps, however would it still be the better practice to use it and include all the relevant metadata? How does using it compare to the approach described earlier?

The rational behind this question is the notion that "if you're developing a Python package, doesn't matter if it's a reusable library or an application, might as well do it right - and specify all the metadata and stuff in a `setup.py`".

TL;DR: What should I use for package management in an application - `setup.py` or `requirements.txt`?

Comment: There's no debate about this: requirements.txt is the right tool.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please the additional paragraph I added: *'The rational behind this question is the notion that "if you're developing a Python package, doesn't matter if it's a reusable library or an application, might as well do it right - and specify all the metadata and stuff in a setup.py".'*. Is this notion mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `requirements.txt` file and install with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

From the [Python Packaging User Guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements/)'s section on install_requires vs Requirements files:

> `install_requires` is a setuptools `setup.py` keyword that should be used to specify what a project minimally needs to run correctly. When the project is installed by pip, this is the specification that is used to install its dependencies.

Also from the [Python Packaging User Guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements/):

> Whereas `install_requires` defines the dependencies for a single project, Requirements Files are often used to define the requirements for a complete python environment.

From this, we can gather that `install_requires` is good when you want to be able to install a project using `pip` - but if you're going to have developers pull code down from a git repository or something like that I would highly suggest using the requirements file route.

In short, the answer to your question *"Which approach is more suitable for a team working on an application?"* is to use `requirements.txt`. If at some point you decide to package this application and upload it to PyPI for the general public's use, you should then put everything in `setup.py` so that when they install it pip will ensure they have all of the dependencies.

Comment: *"This way you're able to set up the whole development environment and dependancies are not only checked on install - they can be updated any time."* - I can always use `git --upgrade` to install additional dependencies, no?

Comment: BTW, does using `setup.py` mean I have to put the app on PyPI or some other index?

Comment: I've never used `--upgrade` as an option to `git` so I'm not sure, and I don't know if you'd have to upload it to PyPI - just use the `requirements.txt` option I don't see any downsides

Comment: Oops, I mean `pip --upgrade`.

Comment: Okay I see now. And I understand your desire to do everything right, but the answer to your question "*Which approach is more suitable for a team working on an application?*" is to use `requirements.txt`. If at some point you decide to package this application and upload it to PyPI for the general public's use, you should then put everything in `setup.py` so that when they install it `pip` will ensure they have all of the dependencies.